# Why we can see change made on jsp on refreshing the page? why not for servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Why we can see change made on jsp on refreshing the page?
why we have to restart the server in case of any changes made in servlet?
what is the difference between both?

Comment: if you are using eclipse, you can use debug mode. Also this will work only for changes inside the method not for any new method definition or arguments changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Servlets are pre compiled class files but jsp will compile at runtime only. And we have jasper listener for jsp it will notify the server when ever we are changing the jsp then server will replace old class file with new one. That's why jsp changes are reflected immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are compiled classes we burry somewhere under WEB-INF but it copies them to its base working location to run them. Until they are changed at THAT location, the changes won't reflect and it does that only at a server restart.

In case of a jsp page When Tomcat is asked to execute a JSP, is compares the modification date of the JSP file with the modification time of the compiled class corresponding to this JSP, and if more recent, it recompiles on the fly before executing it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers stand correct, however you asked "*why do we have to restart the server?*" You do not. You just need the server to utilize the updated file rather than pulling from the cache. There are multiple ways to do this. For Tomcat 8.0.21, it seems true that saving a change in web.xml leads the server to use the files rather than the cache.

The quickest way I found to do this was to add a space, save, remove the space, save again. Also, I did it within a significant area such as within the url-pattern tags.